# Cannot use webService Copy

Tags: server

I want to move some xls file to SP 07 server (C:\folderPath) and i find some web services can do that.

I found that the we can call the `Copy` class from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1524eccb-6f15-4d1d-9ab7-31d14ba73a9b/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-2007-using-web-services?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy) with the URL http:///_vti_bin/Copy.asmx([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).) to upload files to specific folder path. However, i got an error when connect to destination Url.

The error message is:

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Does anyone know how to use the `Copy` web service to move file to to SP 07 server?